# Problema de Invalid key com JWT token e PHP8

Tags: php, jwt, php-8

Bom estou realizando alguns testes do meu projeto no PHP8 e já estou refatorando ele com alguns recursos novos do PHP8.

Porém estou quebrando a cabeça com uma biblioteca que uso para trabalhar com JWT token.

No caso a biblioteca e essa: https://github.com/adhocore/php-jwt

Bom uso ela informando uma key que foi gerada da seguinte forma:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1024 -m PEM -f ws.key
```

Chamo a classe assim:

```
$jwt = new JWT("/var/www/ws.key", "RS256");
```

Porém estou sempre tendo esse erro:

```
"Invalid key: Should be resource of private key"
```

Bom fui analisar o código da biblioteca para verificar onde o erro ocorre:

```
    /**
 * Throw up if key is not resource or file path to private key.
 */
protected function validateKey()
{
    if (\is_string($key = $this->key)) {
        if (\substr($key, 0, 7) !== 'file://') {
            $key = 'file://' . $key;
        }

        $this->key = \openssl_get_privatekey($key, $this->passphrase ?: '');
    }

    if (!\is_resource($this->key)) {
        throw new JWTException('Invalid key: Should be resource of private key', static::ERROR_KEY_INVALID);
    }
}
```

Bom o estranho é que o mesmo código e chave rodam em um servidor php7.4.

Bom não estou conseguindo entender o erro, obs estou rodando Debian 10 e PHP8.

OBS:
Se eu documentar a verificação que está dando o erro:

```
if (!\is_resource($this->key)) {
        throw new JWTException('Invalid key: Should be resource of private key', static::ERROR_KEY_INVALID);
    }
```

Tudo funciona bem, o que indica que a chave esta criada corretamente. Algo no `is_resource` mudou do PHP7.4 para o PHP8 e está causando esse erro. Não estou conseguindo identificar a falha.

Comment: me parece que a key deve ser do tipo resource, por isso da esse erro ao retornar false em `is_resource`

Comment: Pensei nisso também porém não sei como criar a chave assim, estou pesquisando aqui para ver se acho algo.

Comment: O estranho é que funciona no php 7.4